# Custom query in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I'm new to sonata and symfony and I was wondering if there is a way to create a custom query for one of the entities in `configureFormFileds()`?

I need it to build a rather complex admin view over several entities that are many-to-many related via a single intermediate table in a star-like fashion (many joins). My idea was to build a complex query that fetches all the data and then pass it to my form.

I've also tried to map all these relations in doctrine and fetch them one by one in a series of custom forms, but unfortunately, entities must be checked against each other, so that didn't work.

Comment: provide more information please, with code examples, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create custom query for Entity. (example for Doctrine)

```
       ->add(
            'manager',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Manager',
                'class' => 'MainBundle\Entity\Manager',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                        ->where('m.username LIKE :username')
                        ->setParameter('username', $this->getConfigurationPool()
                            ->getContainer()
                            ->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getName()
                        )
                        ->orderBy('m.id', 'ASC');
                },
            ]
        )
```

How create query - lock at the official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder) .

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide some more information to get a precise answer, but regarding your main question:

> I'm new to sonata and symfony and I was wondering if there is a way to
>   create a custom query for one of the entities in
>   configureFormFileds()?

I can answer. In general this is possible, yes. Check out the `query` config parameter of the [sonata_type_model](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-model) or the `callback`  option of the [sonata_type_model_autocomplete](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-model-autocomplete) field type.